# Express (node.js) - res.send only sending part of response

Tags: javascript, node.js, post, express

I am getting some weird behaviour from `res.send()` using the express framework.

Here is my function:

```
user.register(function(err, result) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(err || result));
    res.send(JSON.stringify(err || result));
});
```

It either receives an error or a result object. Here is an example from the `console.log()`:

```
{"name":"AuthError","message":"Password confirmation does not match original password","code":36}
```

However the response received by the client is:

```
{"name":"AuthError","message":"Password confirmation does not match
```

This happens with any error I receive. I don't understand why this is happening as I am just attempting to send a simple JSON string. Can anyone tell what the possible causes of this could be?

**Edit:** I have solved this issue but I would be grateful if someone could explain the reasoning behind it.

I forgot to exit the `user.register()` function whenever an error occured and it continued on to query the database despite that. Once I made sure the function was exited appropriately the response is received in it's entirety... but what could be the cause for this?

Is it because multiple `res.send()` where called before the first had finished (the `user.register()` function would make multiple callback calls if I don't exit it appropriately)? There were no exceptions logged in the console.

Comment: You don't have to stringify objects before calling `res.send` -- it does it for you, and sets the Content-Type appropriately.

Comment: So you've verified that the response JSON is truncated at the client? You've checked the browser console/debugger or whatever?

Comment: @Pointy I have actually managed to fix the issue however I would still appreciate an explanation of why it happened (See edit in post).

Comment: @GeorgeReith well it could be that an exception would cause an output buffer to go un-flushed.

Comment: @pointy There were no exceptions though. Node.js will crash on uncaught exception.

Comment: Hmm well in general an un-flushed buffer is the most likely cause of behavior like that in any communications system. I'm not that familiar with Node applications but it doesn't seem like this sort of detail would involve anything very different from any other similar software, unless it's just a bug in the HTTP stuff.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a call to res.end();
also it seems possible if you are calling res.send more than once, then it may be swallowing the error I'm getting :

> ```
> http.js:707
>     throw new Error('Can\'t set headers after they are sent.');
>           ^
> Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.
>     at ServerResponse.OutgoingMessage.setHeader (http.js:707:11)
>     at ServerResponse.res.setHeader (C:\projects\javascript\node\node_modules\express\node_modules\connect\lib\patch.js:59:22)
>     at ServerResponse.res.set.res.header (C:\projects\javascript\node\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:518:10)
>     at ServerResponse.res.contentType.res.type (C:\projects\javascript\node\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:390:15)
>     at ServerResponse.res.send (C:\projects\javascript\node\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:107:14)
>     at readyToEnd (C:\projects\javascript\node\spawn.js:43:10)
>     at Socket.<anonymous> (C:\projects\javascript\node\spawn.js:22:40)
>     at Socket.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:117:20)
>     at _stream_readable.js:910:16
>     at process._tickCallback (node.js:415:13)
> ```

I wasn't seeing any error thrown until I made a change to when `res.end()` was being called. perhaps that is also happening to you. I'm thinking that `res.send()` wants to set the header for body size, so calling it again would invalidate the header already sent.

If `res.end()` is called before `res.send()` or another `res.send()` is called right before `res.end()` it may not transmit the other part then no error appears to occur from my testing so far.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem with Express 3.3.4 and after updating to Express 3.15.0 I located problem code.

In my case I called **return res.json()** twice. Make sure you not doing the same. New Express versions notify about those situations in console.